# NX Monorepo does not work the hot reload for library

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, angular-module-federation, nx-angular

recently I'm working with NX and have a angular library that used in a component inside a microfrontend. I need this component updated when I make changes in this library Does, anyone know how I can update the component when I updated the library?

I tried to put HMR parameter on true in the project.json and the liveReload with watch parameter too but still not working...